# What is the reverse of passing a Turing test by a human pretending to be a robot that can't be identified?

Tags: research, human-like, turing-test, robots

A Turing Test is a method of inquiry for determining whether or not a computer is capable of thinking like a human being. In an ideal Turing test, it would be clear to differentiate between a real human being and a robot or AI with human characteristics.

However, it is also possible in a Turing test that a human tries to mimic the behaviour of a computer so that the person applying the test cannot distinguish between a human being and a robot/AI.

Is this a concept that is explored much in computer science? As in research into the variations of Turing tests that can be used to identify whether a human is trying to mimic or impersonate as a robot or AI.

Comment: Its a nice question, but it does not really require much of anything to mimic a computer. A computer is a rule based system, a human can follow those rules to arrive at a deterministic result. But human behaviour is not rule based (in the sense we are yet to discover the rules) and hence one cannot mimic it **deterministically** And thus the Turing test. But a simple test might be speed, one difference between humans and computers is the speed of processing, humans are crippled by speed of elctrolytic movement of ions (in the nerves), computers are not.

Comment: @DuttaA isn't psychology our attempt to define the 'rules' of human behaviour? I ask this question because there are also psychological conditions (some of which are physical and affect areas of the brain) that can cause people to lose particular cognitive functions. As a result, they may not be able to recognize faces, have triggers that cause either verbal or non-verbal reactions that are less controllable, or other behaviours that even normal people consider as being 'robotic' or 'abnormal'. As for your point, even using a test of speed would still depend on the type of question right?